# Gitlab feature flag have a review approval?

Tags: gitlab, feature-flags

I would like to use Gitlab Feature Flags instead ones from split.io. But one key feature that I would like to have on Gitlab is the review approval: when a user requests a change on the status of a particular feature flag, to prevent that any user can on/off any feature flag in any moment, it has to be approved to a certain group of users.

The problem is that it seems that Gitlab does not have this feature, but I would like to know if there is a possibility to do such thing.

To have the review approval status feature on Gitlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to achieve this in any of the GitLab tiers (Free, Premium or Ultimate).

There is an open issue, but it doesn't seem that there has been any active development on the matter: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/8239

According to the docs anybody with the developer role and higher can manage feature flags without further restriction possibilities: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Tom, it's a shame that Gitlab didn't included this feature